# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails delete table

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

the following are my sql statements:

```
CREATE DATABASE FOODAPPS;

USE FOODAPPS;

CREATE TABLE Customer (
C_ID        INT             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
C_NAME      VARCHAR(35)     NOT NULL,
C_CON       VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
C_BAL       FLOAT(8,2)      NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(C_ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Restaurant (
R_ID        INT             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
R_ADD       VARCHAR(90)     NOT NULL,
R_CON       VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
R_RATE      DECIMAL(2,1)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(R_ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Purchase (
P_ID        INT             NOT NULL UNIQUE,
C_ID        INT,
P_DATE      DATE            NOT NULL,
P_TIME      TIME            NOT NULL,
R_ID        INT,
P_TOTAL     DECIMAL(10,2)   NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(P_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(C_ID)REFERENCES Customer(C_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(R_ID)REFERENCES Restaurant(R_ID)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES('101', 'Devi', '010-8023456', '200.00');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES('102', 'Jayden', '017-8901234', '650.50');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES('103', 'Stephanie', '018-9013765', '120.30');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES('104', 'Michael', '012-3456789', '450.30');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES('105', 'Abu', '014-2223334', '305.32');

INSERT INTO Restaurant VALUES('201', 'Coconut Street', '088-1234567', '3.5');
INSERT INTO Restaurant VALUES('202', 'Mango Street', '088-2233445', '4.5');
INSERT INTO Restaurant VALUES('203', 'Apple Street', '088-3334445', '4.8');
INSERT INTO Restaurant VALUES('204', 'Peach Street', '088-0110223', '3.7');
INSERT INTO Restaurant VALUES('205', 'Berry Street', '088-8877665', '5.0');

INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES('001', '101', '2024-01-05', '20:08:00', '201', '80.00');
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES('002', '102', '2024-01-06', '14:08:00', '202', '75.00');
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES('003', '103', '2024-01-07', '16:05:00', '203', '70.50');
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES('004', '104', '2024-01-08', '13:25:00', '204', '55.70');
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES('005', '105', '2024-01-09', '19:05:00', '205', '98.50');

SELECT \* FROM Customer;
SELECT \* FROM Restaurant;
SELECT \* FROM Purchase;

START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM Customer WHERE
C_ID = '104';
```

I tried running the sql statements, and all of them were good until I tried to delete a customer from the customer table, it stated an error that says #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`foodapps`.`purchase`, CONSTRAINT `purchase_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`C_ID`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`C_ID`)).

Comment: and what is unclear ?

Comment: how do I delete one customer from the customer table?

Comment: first you need to delete this customer's purchases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the Purchase table you added a foreign key.  This tells the database that the column C_ID can only have values that exist in the table Customer column C_ID.

```
CREATE TABLE Purchase (
...
FOREIGN KEY(C_ID)REFERENCES Customer(C_ID),
```

If you delete customer 104 there would be a row in Purchases with a C_ID that does not exist in the customers table.  That would mean the foreign key constraint is no longer valid.  The database will enforce the constraint and refuse to delete the customer

So before you delete customer 104, first delete the corresponding rows from the Purchase table:

```
DELETE FROM Purchase WHERE C_ID = '104';
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE C_ID = '104';
```